# DNS & Tumblr - setting custom domain and accessing pages on that URL

Tags: redirect, dns, cname

On a tumblr for which I have a custom domain redirect, I have created two A-Record DNS entries. One for the two-level domain (domain,com), and one for three-level domains (www,domain,com). All well and good. This works.

However, I host other pages on the domain, and following the A-Record redirects I can no longer access them. I would like all traffic going to the root domain to be served the tumblr page, but I would still like to be able to serve further pages on that domain that are independent of tumblr

> http;//domain,com/anythinghere/file

The only solution I have been able to think of is to associate tumblr only with the three level domain, and put a redirect file at the root of the two level domain that redirects the three level domain (i.e. http;//domain,com redirects to

> http;//www,domain,com, which then serves tumblr).

this allows me to get at files on

> http;//domain,com/stillaccessible

whereas with the A-name record

> http;//www;domain,com/notacessible)

but it seems clumsy, the URLS are inelegant. Is there another way?

[p.s. have had to change url's to ; and , to avoid site restrictions]

Comment: This question belong maybe better suited to: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: thanks mike - have submitted at http://serverfault.com/questions/669963/accessing-original-files-on-a-domain-which-has-a-record-redirect-to-tumblr